# How can I get a list of transactions of ERC-20 tokens or in USDT from a wallet address?

Tags: wallets, ethereumjs, usdt

I am relatively new to this field and I need to track transactions from wallets that are done in USDT / ERC-20 tokens. I need an API for the same. Please excuse me if my term usages are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can go on etherscan.io where you can see all transactions and accounts on the blockchain.

Etherscan provides, as well as a web interface, an API you can contact with code to get the data you are looking for.

If etherscan is too limited, you can run your own node (https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ for example) and use it's API (https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/server) to get the data you want.